# Updating Electron app

Tags: electron

The Electron framework from GitHub has a feature that lets you automatically update your app by using some server utility called Squirrel. What I am wondering is whether an Electron app can simply just update itself without depending on any server utility. Since an Electron app is basically a web-based app using HTML and Javascript, couldn't you just create an "empty" app that has no UI or code other than some bootup Javascript code that downloads the entire UI and other scripts to run the app?